# Angular form display and bind nested ibject

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular form which displays the content from a table and should be used to edit a student. The student object has an object property course which also has a object property department. I struggle to display and sync the changes of these fields with the student object.

My code can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-damfrb?file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html

The field department should display the name of the department. studycourse the name of the studycourse and degree the degree of the studycourse. For not nested properties I had good results with patchValues, but when I select an entry in the table twice department and courseDegree get assigned at the top level of the object.